# Correct way of setting bookmarks using anchor tag?

Tags: html, tags, html-lists, anchor, bookmarks

**Anchor tag**

```
<section>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Road">ABC</a></li>
                <li><a href="">DEF</a></li>
                <li><a href="">JKL</a>GHI</li>
                <li><a href="">MNO</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PQR</a></li>
            </ul>
</section>
```

I am connecting anchor tag to:-

**Case 1**

```
        <section>
            <h3 id="Road">RoadMap</h3>
            <iframe src="https******"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https******"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https******"></iframe>
        </section>
```

In The above Code the **id** attribute is present in **h3 tag**

**Case 2**

```
<section id="Road">
            <h3>RoadMap</h3>
            <iframe src="https******"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https******"></iframe>
            <iframe src="https******"></iframe>
</section>
```

In the above code, the **id** attribute is present in **section tag**

both approaches are working, want to know which is the best approach when using anchor tag for bookmarks?